# i cannt confirm request in Parity I Can't locate local key file asked by parity to sign a transaction

Tags: parity

How to confirm request in Parity 
I have POA chain from this tutorial https://github.com/paritytech/parity-poa-tutorial 
and as you can see it ask me to select local key and click confirm 
[image]

Comment: And did you try putting the local key and clicking confirm?

Comment: Hi which local key ? as u can see its ask me for file